# 2 datagridcomboboxcolumns in master detail, can be edited and dynamically updated

Tags: wpf, datagrid, itemssource, datagridcomboboxcolumn

The idea is I have LoadGroup and LoadCase. They could be both added or removed  by the user. But loadcase must be child of a loadgroup.

I made 2 datagridcombocolumns. I tried to get the second (detialed) datagridcombocolumn  dynamically update the itemssouce according to the selected load-group in the first column. I have searched for a while. But I couldn't find a relative simple solution to get my data model work.

The **data model** is :

```
public class LoadList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LoadList> Children { get; set;}

    public LoadList() 
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<LoadList>();            
    }
}
```

The **ViewModel** is:

```
{
        ObservableCollection<LoadList> loadgrouplist = new ObservableCollection<LoadList>();
        DG_test.ItemsSource = loadgrouplist;


}
```

I put some **sample data** into the viewmodel.

```
 loadgrouplist.Add(new LoadList { ID = 2, Name = "Load Group 1" });
        loadgrouplist.Add(new LoadList { ID = 2, Name = "Load Group 2" });
        loadgrouplist[0].Children.Add(new LoadList{ID =3 , Name = "Load Case 1"});
        loadgrouplist[0].Children.Add(new LoadList { ID = 3, Name = "Load Case 2" });
        loadgrouplist[1].Children.Add(new LoadList { ID = 3, Name = "Load Case 3" });
        loadgrouplist[1].Children.Add(new LoadList { ID = 3, Name = "Load Case 4" });
```

I have tried different kinds of method to get this thing work.
The most-recent one I tried is something like this:
 **XAML file**

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="DG_test" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dads Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="test_loadgroup" Header="Load Group" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <mui:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="test_mui_loadgroup" Header="MUI Load Group" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group Name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="test_loadgroup" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" DataContext="{Binding Path=Name}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="test_loadcase" Header="Child Name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

How can I get this thing work? 
Many Thanks